# Custom Attribute - getting "not a valid named attribute argument" for an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, custom-attributes

Why do i get this message when i try to use the `MultiselectComperer` value like this:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(OrdersManagementStrings), Name = "PrintSettings")]
[FilterAttribute(IsMultiselect = true, MultiselectComperer=FilterAttribute.eMultiselectComperer.Or)]
public ePrintSettings PrintSettings { get; set; }
```

Here is the code of the custom attribute ... all emuns are public .. and yet i get this message:

> 'MultiselectComperer' is not a valid named attribute argument because
>   it is not a valid attribute parameter
>   type  ....

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class FilterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public enum eMultiselectComperer
    {
        Or,
        And
    }

    public bool IsMultiselect { get; set; }

    public eMultiselectComperer? MultiselectComperer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Horrible title, BTW. What _about_ custom attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `MultiselectComperer` property is nullable. The compiler is complaining because unfortunately you can't make a constant of a nullable type. If you make it non nullable, your class will work just fine.

If you need to represent an third value to the `eMultiselectComperer`, enum other than `Or` and `And` you can create a third enum value as the default value for that enum, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class FilterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public enum eMultiselectComperer
    {
        Unspecified = 0, 
        Or,
        And
    }

    public bool IsMultiselect { get; set; }

    public eMultiselectComperer MultiselectComperer { get; set; }
}
```

This way, if the user doesn't specify a value for the `MultiselectComperer` property when declaring the attribute, it will default to `Unspecified` (or whatever you prefer to call it).

Comment: that did not help .. i have removed the nullable as you said and i still get the same message ..

Comment: @Mortalus Are you sure? You may need to do a clean and rebuild. I've tried this exact code in a sample program in LINQPad and it compiles just fine.

Comment: Very wierd.. I have rebuilt and still got this error.. i'll try to clean + rebuild later..

Comment: Thanks, this helped in my slightly different case. I was trying to use a DateTime, while it is not nullable, it is also not static. I switched to a string, and parsed into a date in the constructor.